# Updating a variable in a function driven by Timer

Tags: ios, swift

I have the below function that works properly when a button is switched to activate it. I want to add a variable that gives each message it's current message number starting from 1. I've tried different methods of setting / updating the value but none of it helped with updating.

I'm very new to Swift / iOS development so I'm sure there is something I'm missing. What I do know is that the message prints to console repeatedly till the button is switched off and the `Timer` is what enables it to continuously run.

```
@IBOutlet weak var stateLabel: UILabel!
//Starts / Stops recording of sensor data via a switch
@IBAction func stateChange(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    if sender.isOn == true {
        startSensorData()
        stateLabel.text = "Stop"
    } else {
        stopSensorData()
        stateLabel.text = "Start"
    }
}


func startSensorData() {
    print("Start Capturing Sensor Data")
    // Making sure sensors are available
    if self.motionManager.isAccelerometerAvailable, self.motionManager.isGyroAvailable {

        // Setting the frequency required for data session
        self.motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 1.0 / 3.0
        self.motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = 1.0 / 3.0

        // Start sensor updates
        self.motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
        self.motionManager.startGyroUpdates()

        // Configure a timer to fetch the data.
        self.motionUpdateTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0/3.0, repeats: true, block: { (timer1) in
            // Get the motion data.
            var loggingSample = 1
            if let accelData = self.motionManager.accelerometerData, let gyroData = self.motionManager.gyroData {

                let accelX = accelData.acceleration.x
                let accelY = accelData.acceleration.y
                let accelZ = accelData.acceleration.z

                let gyroX = gyroData.rotationRate.x
                let gyroY = gyroData.rotationRate.y
                let gyroZ = gyroData.rotationRate.z

                let message = "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970),\(self.device_id),\(loggingSample),\(accelX),\(accelY),\(accelZ),\(gyroX),\(gyroY),\(gyroZ),Processing"
                print(message)
                loggingSample += 1
            }
        }
    )}
}
```

Comment: Update your question showing your attempt to include the message number.

Comment: I've added one of the methods - `loggingSample` as the variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep getting a value of `1` for `loggingSample` because you are using a local variable that gets created as `1` each time.

All you need to do is move the declaration of `loggingSample` to be outside the function so it is a class property.

Move the line:

```
var loggingSample = 1
```

outside the function so it is next to your outlets and other properties.